# Detox tests are not finishing

Tags: react-native, bitrise, detox

I've set up [detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) for E2E testing and Bitrise for continuous integration.

I have set up a very simple initial test suite but for some reason, my tests do not *finish* after they have completed.

**init.js**

```
require('babel-polyfill');
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;

before(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
});

after(async () => {
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

**firstTest.spec.js**

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('UniqueID'))).toBeVisible();
  });
})
```

**Workflow Segment:**
(This is just a *Script step*)

```
brew update

node -v

brew tap wix/brew

brew install wix/brew/applesimutils

npm install -g detox-cli

detox build --configuration ios.sim.release
```

(This will be ported over to a .yml file later)

**package.json** - With all unnecessary stuff omitted.

```
"detox": {
        "configurations": {
            "ios.sim.debug": {
                "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlarmApp.app",
                "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/AlarmApp.xcodeproj -scheme AlarmApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
                "type": "ios.simulator",
                "name": "iPhone 8"
            },
            "ios.sim.release": {
                "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/AlarmApp.app",
                "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/AlarmApp.xcodeproj -scheme AlarmApp -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
                "type": "ios.simulator",
                "name": "iPhone 8"
            }
        }
    }
```

Bitrise successfully executes my tests and I can run them on my local machine so the problem therefore lies within Detox.

The test will pass, but it just hangs.

The `detox.cleanup()` function gets called as I am able to see it in the log file:

```
2017-11-07 16:23:02.802 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] Crash handler setup started.
2017-11-07 16:23:02.805 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] Crash handler setup completed.
2017-11-07 16:23:02.805 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] Enabling accessibility for automation on Simulator.
2017-11-07 16:23:04.427 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Sent: login
2017-11-07 16:23:04.714 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Received: loginSuccess
2017-11-07 16:23:04.795 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ Adding idling resource for queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: com.facebook.react.AccessibilityManagerQueue>
2017-11-07 16:23:04.821 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ Adding idling resource for queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: com.facebook.react.PlatformConstantsQueue>
2017-11-07 16:23:05.276 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Sent: ready
2017-11-07 16:23:05.287 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Received: reactNativeReload
2017-11-07 16:23:05.293 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ Adding idling resource for queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: com.facebook.react.AccessibilityManagerQueue>
2017-11-07 16:23:05.293 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ Adding idling resource for queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: com.facebook.react.PlatformConstantsQueue>
2017-11-07 16:23:05.402 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Sent: ready
2017-11-07 16:23:05.409 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Received: invoke
2017-11-07 16:23:05.836 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Sent: invokeResult
2017-11-07 16:23:05.844 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Received: cleanup
2017-11-07 16:23:05.845 AlarmApp[15771:1271275] ☣️ DETOX:: Detox Action Sent: cleanupDone
```

Any help would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Viktor from Bitrise.

One of our users reported the same issue (although I'm not sure if they used detox, but React Native for sure and same "tests finished but the process does not exist" issue).

I tried to get as much info as possible about this, as we did debug with them in a temporary virtual machine:

> Thanks, I think I found the problem! A couple of our old tests were using react-native-test-renderer instead of enzyme like the newer tests. They were rendering a component with a looping animation, which is what was causing the hang. Once I switched to shallow rendering the problem was fixed. Thanks for your help!

Also worth to mention that the issue started to happen when they upgraded the React Native version in their project

> I imagine that in previous versions of React Native, the renderer was not running all the code in the child components, but something changed and now it does. The code in question does loop indefinitely, so it's not surprising it was causing a hang.

I hope this helps @Dan, if it would not just let me know or ping our support ;)